# Regarding the equation derivations of the resonant state of an asynchronous buck converter observing zero voltage switching

Tags: buck, switching, resonance, zvs, resonant

I'm currently reading this article of Bill Andreycak to understand the mathematics behind zero voltage switching: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua159/slua159.pdf?ts=1710666811170&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F. At present, I'm currently reading on the ZVS Design Equations portion.

When it comes to the derivation the design equations for the initial conditions and the capacitor charging state, I feel like I totally got the hang of it. However, I am not sure I totally understand the derivations/circuit analysis for the resonant state.

First of all, here's my understanding of the resonant state:

*At t<sub>1</sub>*

1. This state is triggered when/starts after the resonant capacitor has has fully charged at t<sub>1</sub>. At this very moment, i<sub>Cr</sub> should be equal to I<sub>OUT</sub> but it should be gearing to decrease to zero.
2. As the parallel combination of C<sub>R</sub> and Q<sub>1</sub> would now theoretically behave like an open circuit as C<sub>R</sub> have now been fully charged, the cathode of the freewheeling diode D<sub>0</sub> now effectively has a lower voltage received compared to its anode. In short, the freewheeling diode D<sub>0</sub> should now start conducting, triggering the output inductor to act as a current source (in other words, the voltage polarity of output inductor should flip).
3. The resonant inductor L<sub>r</sub> also acts a current source (in other words, the voltage polarity of resonant inductor should flip) since the open circuit behavior of C<sub>R</sub> and Q<sub>1</sub> at the beginning of this state would indicate a current interruption, although, of course, the direction of i<sub>Lr</sub> should remain as is.
4. The resonant inductor current i<sub>LR</sub> should be equal to IOUT at this specific period, but should also gear to decrease afterwards. It is also equal to i<sub>CR</sub>.

*Between t<sub>1</sub> to t<sub>2</sub>*

1. The resonant capacitor current i<sub>CR</sub> and the resonant inductor current i<sub>Lr</sub> continues to be equal, however, they're no longer equal to the output current I<sub>OUT</sub>. As mentioned, i<sub>CR</sub> and  i<sub>Lr</sub> is expected to be decreasing throughout this duration (or at least it's how I understood it).
2. The resonant inductor voltage V<sub>LR</sub> should also be decreasing to some value throughout this duration.

With that understanding, this is how I would implement polarities and directions in the schematic diagram at resonant state for circuit analysis:

[image]

Now, when I try to derive the equations myself for the t<sub>1</sub> to t<sub>2</sub> duration, although it feels like I got the KVL right, ******I don't think I understand the decision behind designating the sine function to the resonant inductor voltage and the cosine function to the resonant inductor current**.* I mean, ELI the ICE man right?*** So following that, the resonant inductor voltage should follow a cosine function while the resonant inductor current should follow a sine function, right?

If you check out the article, you would see that these are the derived equations during resonant state:

[image]

I mean they do mention that the current should follow a cosine function but proceeds to not give an explanation why:

[image]

**If somebody could explain to why the design equations for the resonant state are the way they are, it would greatly help me**. Perhaps somebody could generously go over the proper way of circuit analysis for me because that maybe the reason why there's a disconnect from my end.

Comment: Voltage can be sine as long as current is -cosine. I use CIVIL (you can work it out I'm sure).

Comment: Are you familiar with the operation of a class E switching amplifier?